# How to add more commands to Git Bash?

Tags: windows, git-bash

I am working on windows machine and I use bash shell which comes with Git. But there are many utilities which are missing in this version of bash shell.

How can I install more commands on this shell?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `many utilities are missing in this version of bash shell`. Please add what commands are missing that you would like to use.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/872557/212162 for a much more recent and easier way of using utilities that aren't included by default.

Answer (score 26):

There are two versions of Git that you are likely to be using - the [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/) distribution or [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

### Installing Additional Utilities For Cygwin

Although you might have only installed Git as a part of your Cygwin install (if you used Cygwin), Cygwin has a program called [setup.exe](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) which you can use to add packages. Essentially, all you have to do is run `setup.exe` and pick out what programs you want installed when you get to the **Select Packages** window. The introduction [here](http://www.dogsbodynet.com/openr/install_cygwin.html) provides a good overview with images that detail the process.

Cygwin's installer is smart enough to figure out that you have a preexisting installation, and it will add packages to your installation (instead of nuking it and starting over).

### MSYS

The other version of Git you are probably using (if not Cygwin) is msysgit. Because msysgit installs a minimal Unix environment which is not really compatible with MinGW, you'll end up having to install the MinGW suite beside msysgit. The MinGW [Getting Started](https://mingw.osdn.io/index.html?page=docrefs.html) page gives a detailed overview on how to go about getting MinGW installed - since I have no experience with MinGW personally, all I can really do is refer you to their instructions.

You'll then have to migrate your msysgit installation into MinGW. This can be accomplished by doing the following (taken from [here](http://www.seebs.net/log/articles/640/getting-git-under-mingw)). After the following sequence is done, MinGW should find your Git installation.

```
cd GITDIR # Where GITDIR is wherever inside Program Files you put Git
cp bin/git* /MINGW/bin # Where MINGW is wherever you put MinGW
cp -r libexec/git* /MINGW/libexec
cp -r share/git* /MINGW/share
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, do not try to use the cygwin installer on the msysgit package. It partially works... but while resolving dependencies, it will *replace sh.exe* (which changes your environment significantly).

Comment: How do I know if my git-bash use cygwin or msys ?

Comment: I installed from https://git-scm.com/download/win is that msysgit or cygwin? EDIT Figured it out. Rather than delete this comment, I'll say that it's msysgit.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement - Please also say how you figured it out, for other readers (like myself) who have asked themselves the same question.

Comment: @Ioanna I think I asked in #git on freenode, and they gave a compelling argument. I'm now using Cygwin, and I'm as happy as I could be given the broken, virus-like OS :-)

Comment: You can tell what you have installed by running `uname -o` in the bash terminal.

Answer (score 25):

With recent [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) installations, installing additional shell scripts and programs is pretty easy.

Simply put the executables into `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` (`%ProgramFiles%\Git\usr\bin`).

I recommend installing git using [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) `choco install git --params "/GitAndUnixToolsOnPath /WindowsTerminal"`, because you can update git (and all other tools installed with chocolatey) by executing `choco upgrade all`.

### Example for [git-fresh](https://github.com/imsky/git-fresh)

Copy the file [git-fresh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/imsky/git-fresh/master/git-fresh) to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

### Example for [adr-tools](https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools)

1. Download a zip package from the [releases page](https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools/releases)
2. Unzip the package
3. Copy everything from `src/` into `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`

Comment: This is awesome. Didn't realize that chocolately is basically the package manager.

Comment: W11, MSysGit version of Git Bash. Folder was in `%UserProfile%/AppData/Local/Programs/Git` aka `%LocalAppData%/Programs/Git`.

Answer (score 17):

#### to add `rsync`

You can download the rsync file directly from [mysys](http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/).  Just search the page for `rsync` and choose the one with the latest date / latest version number.
Unpack this file (e.g. `rsync-3.1.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`) via

```
tar -xf rsync-3.1.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Then copy rsync at `./usr/bin/rsync.exe`
and paste it into the `/usr/bin folder` of your Git installation.
On my machine, that is `C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/`

You can see the location of your Git installation via

```
where git
```

Here is a GitHub gist by "hisplan" (Jaeyoung Chun) that has instructions along with a link to the 3.1.3-1 version of rsync: [add-rsync-to-git-bash](https://gist.github.com/hisplan/ee54e48f17b92c6609ac16f83073dde6).

Note: I could not unpack the `rsync-3.1.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` file directly into the Git folder, because permissions did not allow it.  And Git Bash does not have `sudo`.
But I could unpack it directly into my `Downloads` folder no problem.
It's just as well, because you only need the `rsync.exe` file anyway.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using msysgit a simple option is to just install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and then add the MINGW path to the .bashrc file you are using for your Git installation:

```
    PATH=$PATH:/MINGW/msys/1.0/bin
```

...where MINGW is where you installed MinGW

That way you can use the MinGW tools directly from your Git bash installation, and if you need another bash tool you can just install it to MinGW.

Answer (score 4):

You can download additional Unix unitities `Wget, Hugo, Xpdf, make, Nano` from here: https://gist.github.com/evanwill/0207876c3243bbb6863e65ec5dc3f058

### Wget

- Download the lastest wget binary for windows from [eternallybored](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) (they are available as a zip with documentation, or just an exe)
- If you downloaded the zip, extract all (if windows built in zip utility gives an error, use [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)).
- Rename the file `wget64.exe` to `wget.exe` if necessary.
- Move `wget.exe` to your `Git\mingw64\bin\`.

*Note: I have noticed some bugs when using Wget on Git Bash to create WARC files. For more complex use of Wget, consider [Cygwin](https://evanwill.github.io/_drafts/notes/cygwin.html) instead.*

### Hugo

[Hugo](http://gohugo.io/) static site generator can be downloaded as a binary and does not have a installer.
Dropping it into your `bin` easily adds it to your Git Bash path.
Grab the Windows 64-bit version from the [releases page](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases).
Unzip the download, then copy `hugo.exe` into your `Git\mingw64\bin` directory.

### Xpdf

[Xpdf](http://www.xpdfreader.com/index.html) is a handy utility for manipulating PDF files.

- Download the [windows version "Xpdf tools"](http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html).
- Extract zip.
- Copy the contents of `xpdf-tools-win-4.00\bin64\` into your `Git\mingw64\bin\`.
- Check the [docs](http://www.xpdfreader.com/support.html) to get started with tools such as `pdftotext` and `pdftopng`.

### make

- Go to [ezwinports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/).
- Download `make-4.1-2-without-guile-w32-bin.zip` (get the version without guile).
- Extract zip.
- Copy the contents to your `Git\mingw64\` merging the folders, but do NOT overwrite/replace any existing files.

### Nano

> As of 2018, recent versions of Git Bash include Nano, so this is unnecessary!

- Download the Nano binary from Nano [win32-support](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/win32-support/) page. You just need the `.exe` file, which is named `nano-git-0d9a7347243.exe` (as of this writing).
- Rename the file to `nano.exe`, and copy to the `mingw64\bin` directory.
- This version of Nano will not work with Git Bash alone, but can be invoked using `winpty`, for example, `winpty nano test.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

> install "Git for Windows SDK" (scroll to the bottom of https://gitforwindows.org/ which provides a link to download installer for it from https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/releases/latest)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32712133/package-management-in-git-for-windows/52105321#52105321

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the following and installed emacs to git-bash..
>   1. Install msys2 somewhere(does not have to be same computer).
>   2. Under msys2, run the following:
>
> ```
>    cd /tmp
>     mkdir -p var/lib
>     cp -R /var/lib/pacman var/lib/
>     pacman -Sr /tmp emacs
>     tar zcf emacs.tar.gz usr
> ```
>
> 3. Copy `emacs.tar.gz` to where you can access from git-bash, then under git-bash:
>
>    tar zxf emacs.tar.gz -C /
>          emacs
>
> That's all, good luck.

After the first post, I tried an other computer but not working. It turns out that some dlls is missing in git-bash. Then I tested in a clean virtual machine with the following steps:

1. Install [msys2-x86_64-20180531](http://repo.msys2.org/distrib/x86_64/msys2-x86_64-20180531.exe) and [Git-2.19.1-64-bit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.19.1.windows.1/Git-2.19.1-64-bit.exe).
2. Update msys2, open msys64 console and run:

   ```
   pacman -Syyu
   ```

   Close msys64 console when prompted, then run the above command again.
3. Get emacs files as the previous steps(run the following in msys64):

   ```
   cd /tmp
   mkdir -p var/lib
   cp -R /var/lib/pacman var/lib/
   pacman -Sr /tmp emacs
   tar zcf emacs.tar.gz usr
   mv emacs.tar.gz /c/tmp
   ```

   ps: I once tried the above steps in /d/tmp instead of /tmp and was not able to install emacs to it.
4. Open git-bash and extract emacs files:

   ```
   cd /c/tmp
   tar zxf emacs.tar.gz -C /
   ```

   It will complain missing shared library "?" on trying to run emacs now. The "?" will not revealed to any readable
5. Go back to msys64 and get the msys2 dlls's:

   ```
   ls --color=never /bin/*.dll > /c/tmp/1.txt
   ```
6. In git-bash compare dlls with msys:

   ```
   cd /c/tmp
   git init
   git add 1.txt && git commit
   ls --color=never /bin/*.dll | sed 's#\*$##g' > /c/tmp/1.txt
   git diff 1.txt | grep '^-' | sed '1d' | sed 's#^-/bin/##g' > diff_dlls.txt
   ```

   In my case, there are 26 dlls in diff_dlls.txt.
7. Copy the dlls from msys64 to git-bash:

   In msys64:

   ```
   mkdir /c/tmp/dlls
   cat /c/tmp/diff_dlls.txt | xargs -I {} cp /bin/{} /c/tmp/dlls
   ```

   In git-bash:

   ```
   cp /c/tmp/dlls/* /bin
   ```
8. All done, now emacs runs in git-bash. Some of the 26 dlls may not be necessary, but I'd prefer to save my time instead of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty simple answer today that worked for `rsync`.

1. Install git bash for Windows
2. Download `rsync` from [futureware.at](http://www2.futureware.at/~nickoe/msys2-mirror/msys/x86_64/rsync-3.1.2-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz)*
3. Extract to anywhere, I choose `C:\rsync-3.1.2-2-x86_64.pkg`
4. Add the **bin** folder to the top of your system path

* I do not know who is behind futureware.at, I would prefer to link to a more primary source.

Comment: @mike your answer is similar, except that I didn't install cygwin64

Answer (score 0):

If using Git bash for Windows (MinGW64), I had a very hard time getting rsync to be added to it.  kept getting error: dup() in/out/err failed

Instead, using Cygwin worked eventually.

Steps I took to use rysnc in Gitbash for Windows

1. Install gitbash for windows
2. Install cygwin64
3. Add the cygwin path to the Windows path variable

   > Windows-> System->advanced Setings->Environment Variables
   >
   > > Add a path for C:\cygwin64\bin\
4. Close and re-open gitbash
   Now gitbash will find the rsync.exe in the cygwin\bin
5. I was getting an incompatible version error for cygwin1.dll

   > *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected
6. Although some said a reboot will fix this, it did not.
7. To resolve the version error, I copied the cygwin\bin directory from an older version of cygwin  - version 1.7.30 worked

Comment: Don't do this.  See [Use cygwin executable in git bash script](https://superuser.com/questions/1177972/use-cygwin-executable-in-git-bash-script) for why.

Answer (score 0):

One could extend the number of features in git-bash by creating scripts and call them by defining them in the `~/.bash_profile` file.

**Example**

If one would like to use the `watch` command, then this script could be added to the `~/.bash_profile`:

https://gist.github.com/espaciomore/28e24ce4f91177c0964f4f67bb5c5fda

> ```
> ARGS="${@}"
> clear;
> while(true); do
>   OUTPUT=`$ARGS`
>   clear
>   echo -e "${OUTPUT[@]}"
> done
> ```

and wrap it inside a function:

```
watch() {
  ARGS="${@}"
  clear;
  while(true); do
    OUTPUT=`$ARGS`
    clear
    echo -e "${OUTPUT[@]}"
  done
}
```

As soon as one saves the file and runs `source ~/.bash_profile` then one should be able to watch the output of commands.

Answer (score 0):

The above instructions are slightly outdated. Here is what recently worked for me. Use linux to download and extract necessary files:

```
sudo apt-get install zstd  # download unpack tool

# get rsync and necessary libraries
wget http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/rsync-3.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
wget http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/libzstd-1.5.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
wget http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/libxxhash-0.7.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst


# unpack
tar -I zstd -xvf rsync-3.2.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
tar -I zstd -xvf libzstd-1.5.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
tar -I zstd -xvf libxxhash-0.7.4-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
```

now copy everything to Windows...
for example `MinGW/bin` or `Git/usr` as explained above

Answer (score 0):

### To get `rsync` for Windows 10, this [guide](https://alanbarber.com/post/installing-rsync-on-windows/) the only one worked for me

Steps in summary:

1. Download “mingw-get-setup.exe” from the MinGW SourceForge Project Site (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/).
2. Run the “mingw-get-setup.exe” and click the “Install” button. Then, navigate the left side options and select “MSYS”. Then locate and select only the “msys-rsync” bin package. Then, from the "Installation" drop down menu select “Apply Changes”.
3. Copy the following four files from the MinGW msys bin folder “C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin” to the Git bin folder “C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin”

```
msys-iconv-2.dll
msys-intl-8.dll
msys-popt-0.dll
rsync.exe
```

then in Git Bash, run the following 2 commands:

```
echo '/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/rsync "$@"' >/usr/bin/rsync
chmod +x /usr/bin/rsync
```

in Git Bash, run below command to check rsync is working:

```
rsync --version
```

4. (Optional) Delete entire C:/MinGW folder